# How Does std::forward_list::sort Work in NlogN Time?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I can't imagine how to reorder a singly linked list with decent time complexity (The library says it takes "approximately" NlogN). Is there a name for the algorithm used that I could use to find educational material about it? I looked at the code in the standard library, but I couldn't figure much out other than a merge takes place near the end of one of the few functions named `sort` or `sort2`. Below are some of the functions used:

```
    template <class _Pr2>
    static void _Sort(_Nodeptr _BFirst, _Pr2 _Pred) {
        auto _BMid       = _Sort2(_BFirst, _Pred);
        size_type _Bound = 2;
        do {
            if (!_BMid->_Next) {
                return;
            }

            const auto _BLast = _Sort(_BMid, _Bound, _Pred);
            _BMid             = _Inplace_merge(_BFirst, _BMid, _BLast, _Pred);
            _Bound <<= 1;
        } while (_Bound != 0);
    }
```

```
    template <class _Pr2>
    static _Nodeptr _Sort(const _Nodeptr _BFirst, size_type _Bound, _Pr2 _Pred) {
        // Sort (_BFirst, _BFirst + _Bound), unless nullptr is encountered.
        // Returns a pointer one before the end of the sorted region.
        if (_Bound <= 2) {
            return _Sort2(_BFirst, _Pred);
        }

        const auto _Half_bound = _Bound / 2;
        const auto _BMid       = _Sort(_BFirst, _Half_bound, _Pred);
        if (!_BMid->_Next) {
            return _BMid;
        }

        const auto _BLast = _Sort(_BMid, _Half_bound, _Pred);
        return _Inplace_merge(_BFirst, _BMid, _BLast, _Pred);
    }
```

```
    template <class _Pr2>
    static _Nodeptr _Inplace_merge(_Nodeptr _BFirst1, const _Nodeptr _BMid, const _Nodeptr _BLast, _Pr2 _Pred) {
        // Merge the sorted ranges (_BFirst1, _BMid] and (_BMid, _BLast)
        // Returns one before the new logical end of the range.
        auto _First2 = _BMid->_Next;
        for (;;) { // process 1 splice
            _Nodeptr _First1;
            for (;;) { // advance _BFirst1 over elements already in position
                if (_BFirst1 == _BMid) {
                    return _BLast;
                }

                _First1 = _BFirst1->_Next;
                if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, _First2->_Myval, _First1->_Myval)) {
                    // _First2->_Myval is out of order
                    break;
                }

                // _First1->_Myval is already in position; advance
                _BFirst1 = _First1;
            }

            // find the end of the "run" of elements less than _First1->_Myval in the 2nd range
            auto _BRun_end = _First2;
            _Nodeptr _Run_end;
            for (;;) {
                _Run_end = _BRun_end->_Next;
                if (_BRun_end == _BLast) {
                    break;
                }

                if (!_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, _Run_end->_Myval, _First1->_Myval)) {
                    // _Run_end is the first element in (_BMid->_Myval, _BLast->_Myval) that shouldn't precede
                    // _First1->_Myval.
                    // After the splice _First1->_Myval will be in position and must not be compared again.
                    break;
                }

                _BRun_end = _Run_end;
            }

            _BMid->_Next     = _Run_end; // snip out the run from its old position
            _BFirst1->_Next  = _First2; // insert into new position
            _BRun_end->_Next = _First1;
            if (_BRun_end == _BLast) {
                return _BMid;
            }

            _BFirst1 = _First1;
            _First2  = _Run_end;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Build a vector with pointers to the list, sort the vector in n logn, build another list from the sorted vector. It's probably not what the std lib does, but has the right time complexity.

Comment: @al3c Their algorithm does an in place merge too rather than needing O(n) memory as far as I can see, which makes it much more interesting from a space and time complexity point of view. What you're talking about isn't just probably not what they do. It definitely isn't as we can see the code. Things like that and `multiset<int> sorter{begin(fl), end(fl)}` `forward_list<int> sorted_fl{begin(sorter), end(sorter)}` aren't interesting. Additionally, all iterators into the `forward_list` are still valid after `forward_list::sort` is called whereas your new `forward_list` will have new iterators.

Comment: @al3c Additionally, such a strategy, beyond not working with some algorithms that rely on valid iterators after the sorting, would also copy construct your elements twice, once when going from the `forward_list` to `vector` and again when going from the `vector` to the `forward_list`. `forward_list::sort` does not construct new objects.

Comment: @OP, what @ al3c said does answer your question "how can it be `O(nlogn)`". And you can definitely use the same node, you just overwrite their next pointer, then all iterator (and reference to element) do keep valid.

Comment: @appleapple No, it doesn't. The question was specifically about sorting a linked list. Not sorting it somewhere else. I asked specifically what a chunk of code is doing, which operates on `Node`s. They're not using sort with random access iterators, nor are they using O(n) memory. Additionally, `forward_list` has no way to get a `Node` type for you to play around with its internal structure, so no, a solution based on sorting the elements in or with another data structure cannot leave iterators into the `forward_list` pointing to the same elements now at different, sorted positions.

Comment: @user904963 what you think `_Nodeptr`  is?

Comment: @user904963 and if you're asking this particular algorithm, you don't even provide `_Sort2` in the question which is used many times.

Comment: @user904963 futher more, `std::forward_list::sort` is a member function, "no way to play around with its internal structure" is simply nonsense.

Comment: @appleapple This is getting embarrassing. You clearly don't know C++. `_Nodeptr` is an implementation detail used in the internals of `forward_list`. There is no way to access it. I'm actually shocked. It seems like you're trolling at this point. There is no way for a user of `forward_list` to sort one in a way that prevents superfluous copies or retains iterator validity other than to call `forward_list::sort`. The suggestion to say `vector<int> v{begin(fl), end(fl)};`, then `sort(begin(v), end(v)), and then `forward_list sorted_fl{begin(v), end(v)}` made no sense for these reasons.

Comment: @user904963 what i proposed doesn't require moving anything you can sort a vector of list iterators. Still what i suggested is, as far as I can tell, standard compliant. You can recostruct a list keeping all of its iterators valid.

Comment: @al3c, You seem to have interpreted my straight question, asking how something can be sorted with O(nlogn) time and O(1) space complexities using only `ForwardIterator`s as me asking how to break into the STL source code and inject an awful solution to the problem using O(n) memory. There might be a language barrier, because my question was perfectly clear: What algorithm or technique are they using? They are not using an `std::vector` of node objects and calling `std::sort`. Instead, they're using `_sort2`, `_sort`, and `_Inplace_merge`. Please, stop spamming your off topic screed.

Comment: @user904963 you never said you wanted O(1) space complexity, which by the way the standard doesn't require. The STL doesn't have, per se, a source code, implementations of the STL do. If your question is how does the STL implemation of XYZ std lib implement std::forward_list::sort then I'd agree with you I didn't answer that. But you never referred you to some named implementation. You have some sorce code of some unspecified implementation which could contain a possible answer to your question. I gave you and answer that didn't follow that hint.

Comment: @ user904963 not sure what you're arguing, and saying I don't know c++ is no help for you. `std::forward_list::sort` can be implemented as @al3c said, period.

Comment: @appleapple Your perspective is incredibly bizarre. I asked specifically about how `forward_list::sort` works and posted its code. `std::sort` is not being used on a constructed `vector` of nodes. Your comments are all off topic. This understanding of my question is painfully obvious by the fact that I posted the bottom up merge sort they used (I know its strategy as jwezorek answered the question). It'd be like me posting a picture of a mouse trap, asking how to kill a mouse, and you enter into the room and say, "Just use a shotgun. It'll work fine."

Comment: @user904963 you seem to believe there's one and only implementation of STL algorithms. That's not true at all. Did you want to ask how the code you posted works? Well your question didn't ask that, I'm sorry. You asked how one specific constraint can be achieved, and as it turns out there are answers to that specific question that don't go via the more complicated implementation you happen to have found. Please reread your question carefully, and please be kinder to people who take the time to help you out.

Comment: @al3c You seem to lack the principle of charity. If there were only one implementation, I'd not have posted code snippets from a particular one. Also, no implementations of `forward_list::sort` would use O(n) memory. If you look at the standard, it states O(nlogn) time complexity and O(1) memory. You really need to learn more about C++ as well as stop upvoting yourself on a ghost account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bottom up" variants of merge sort can sort a linked list in O(n log n) time and O(1) space. [See the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists). If O(1) space isn't a requirement then you can construct an array of pointers into the list, sort that using any O(n log n) sorting algorithm, and then rebuild the list from your sorted copy.

Comment: It seems to be using a bottom up merge sort. That algorithm is a good starting place to understand what they wrote.